# Adversary argument and proving a lower bound of an algorithm. How does it work?

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, time-complexity, lower-bounds, adversary

I need to understand how adversary argument works to prove the lower bound of an algorithm. For now, I am looking to prove that a "certain" algorithm that takes in input array requires *omega(n)* comparisons. Basically it needs to compare the *ith* element with *i+1th* element, then *i+1* to *i+2* element and so on.

The adversary needs to make sure that algorithm does most of the work; so I am thinking about dynamically creating input array, and making the algorithm to compare all the elements.

In this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fbQMmvIZ3Oo&t=192s&ab_channel=AlexChen), he is also using adversary argument to prove equality testing (finding duplicates) and in it he is using majority voting technique.

I am however, still quite confused how do we implement such a strategy to prove lower bounds. What sort of adversary we need to design?

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Here is the first hit for "adversary argument" in a popular search engine: https://jeffe.cs.illinois.edu/teaching/algorithms/notes/13-adversary.pdf